# "I didn´t say it was" or "...it is"?

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

I surely know the expression: "I didn´t say it was..." and heard people say it many times but people also seem to use " I didn´t say it is".

I should be "was", shouldn´t it? Is there any difference?

Comment: Look up [reported speech](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/tense-changes-when-using-reported-speech/)  and [backshifting](https://www.thoughtco.com/backshift-sequence-of-tense-rule-in-grammar-1689017).   Technically, "I didn't say it was" would be correct, but it seems like English usage is changing, and more and more people are not backshifting if the fact is still true.

Comment: The ThoughtCo page mentions this under *Exceptions to Backshifting*: "In certain situations, the sequence of tense rules are relaxed and backshifting is not required. Essentially, backshifting is not required if a statement about the present or future still holds."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In proper grammatical usage, it depends on when you "**said**" it [is/was], whether or not it still [is]. It all depends on when you supposedly said something, whether you should have been speaking in past or present tense.

However, English speakers use these terms pretty much interchangeably, mostly using "Was"

Comment: Thanks! Could you give some examples for the things you describe? I just want to make sure I get it right this time.

Comment: Example 1: Pretend I was talking to a friend about a trip I went on 2 years ago, on which I went to a zoo. My friend may say "did you get lost in the zoo? You told me last year that it was big." I would reply "I didn't say it was" because the event was in the past during the first conversation.

Comment: Example 2: If I decided to go on a trip to a zoo with my friend, they may tell me "you said the zoo's big, right?" and I would reply "I never said it is" because at the time being, the zoo *still* isn't big